# How do i copy my System into Parallels?

Tags: parallels-desktop, bootable-disk

Is it even possible ?

I want to boot my actual Mac OS X Server in Parallels. ( With all the programs and setting )
The Reason is : I want to create a Test-System, where i can experiment without harming the running system.
PLEASE HELP ME. I need this JOB !!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
Here is a post on the Parallels Forum that will show you how:
http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?113931-Convert-Physical-Lion-Drive-to-virtual

In a nutshell:

1) Clean up the system hard drive

2) Run Time Machine on a fresh drive

3) Created a new VM, using the Install Mountain Lion package.

4) The installer lets you use an existing Time Machine backup (actually, you pick the option that says "Existing Disk" or something like that, which also happens to work with Time Machine backups). This doesn't work, however, because it says the backup was from a different machine.

5) Let the ML Installer go through its paces. It asks again if I want to migrate existing data, and this time the Time Machine backup works just fine.

-OR-

Use Carbon Copy Cloner to make a .dmg of the original drive and do some juggling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I've included a link which examples using Parallels to run both 10.7 and 10.8, though the basics apply regardless of version.

http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/os-x/install-two-versions-of-os-x-on-one-mac-using-parallels/